How to plot posterior marginal means for categorical variables?
I ran this model. Each categorical variable has three levels. How can I plot the results such as posterior marginal means for each six levels by country?
model <- brm(
  bf(binary ~ categorical1 + categorical2 + (1 | id) + (1 | country)),
  data = data,
  family = bernoulli(link = "logit"),
  prior = priors,
  chains = 8, iter = 2000, seed = 345)


You can use marginaleffects to do this.  See the code below.  My answer assumes you want to integrate over the distribution of future id and not the observed id.
library(brms)
library(marginaleffects)

n <- 150
cat1 <- sample(letters[1:3], size=n, replace=T)
country <- sample(letters[1:10], size=n, replace=T)
id <- sample(letters[1:10], size=n, replace=T)
X <- model.matrix(~cat1)
Z <- model.matrix(~country-1)
Z2 <- model.matrix(~id-1)


beta <- c(-2, 0.8, 0.3)
gamma <- rnorm(ncol(Z), 0, 0.2)
gamma2 <- rnorm(ncol(Z2), 0, 0.2)
eta <- X %*% beta + Z %*% gamma + Z2 %*% gamma2
p <- plogis(eta)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, p)

#----

d <- tibble(cat1, country, y, id=id)
model <- brm(
  y ~ cat1 + (1|country) + (1|id), 
  data=d,
  family = bernoulli(),
  backend = 'cmdstanr'
)

dg <- datagrid(model=model, by=c('country','cat1'), id = -1)


predictions(
  model, 
  newdata = dg,
  allow_new_levels = T
) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cat1, estimate, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
  geom_pointrange() + 
  facet_wrap(~country, labeller = label_both)



